# grunt-contrib-connect server can't connect t localhost

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect

My Gruntfile:

```
...
connect: {
  server: {
    options: {
      port: 8000,
      hostname: 'localhost',
      base: '.'
    }
  }
}
...
```

Then, when I run `grunt connect`, I see this:

```
❯ grunt connect
  Running "connect:server" (connect) task
  Started connect web server on http://localhost:8000

  Done, without errors.
❯
```

Then that's it. If I got to my localhost:8000. I see chrome can't connect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use **grunt-contrib-connect** as a dev server, please look at [keepalive](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect#keepalive) option.

According to the documentation:

> Note that this server only runs as long as grunt is running. Once
>   grunt's tasks have completed, the web server stops. This behavior can
>   be changed with the *keepalive* option, and can be enabled ad-hoc by
>   running the task like `grunt connect:keepalive`.

Comment: `keepalive` didn't help. same thing.

Comment: nevermind, it did work, had to put `keepalive` in the options hash, I was putting it in the connect: hash. thanks!